# How to append variables to a url which already has variables?

Tags: php, regex, url

So, the situation I'm currently in is a wee bit complicated (for me that is), but I'm gonna give it a try.

I would like to run to a snippet of HTML and extract all the links referring to my own domain. Next I want to append these URL's with a predefined string of GET vars. For example, I want to append '?var1=2&var2=4' to 'http://www.domain.com/page/' thus creating 'http://www.domain.com/page/?var1=2&var2=4'.

The method I'm currently applying is a simple preg_replace function (PHP), but here is when it gets interesting. How do i create valid appended url's when they already have some GET vars at the end? For example, it could create a url like this: 'http://www.domain.com/page/?already=here&another=one?var1=2&var2=4' 
thus breaking the GET data.

So to conclude, what I'm looking for is a reg exp which can cope with these scenarios, create my extended url and write it back to the HTML snippet.

This is what I have so far:

```
$sHTML = preg_replace("'href=\"($domainURL.*?[\/$])\"'", 'href="\1' . $appendedTags . '"', $sHTML);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you should probably encode the second query-string with Base64 and then in your PHP when you read from that, decode it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to what [Elazar Leibovich](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817101/how-to-append-variables-to-a-url-which-already-has-variables/817172#817172) suggested, I'd parse the query string with [`parse_str()`](http://de3.php.net/parse_str), modify the resulting array to my needs and then use [`http_build_query()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to rebuild the query string. This way you won't have any duplicates within your query string and you don't have to bother yourself with url-encoding your query-parts.

The complete example would then look like (augmenting [Elazar Leibovich](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817101/how-to-append-variables-to-a-url-which-already-has-variables/817172#817172) code):

```
$broken = parse_url($url);
$query = parse_str($broken['query']);
$query['var1'] = 1;
$query['var2'] = 2;
$broken['query'] = http_build_query($query);
return $broken['scheme'] . '://' . $broken['host'] . $broken['path'] .
  '?' . $broken['query'] . '#' . $broken['fragment'];
```

Comment: Never knew those functions even existed, thanks all. Wish I could accept both answers, but chose yours for the most upvotes and complete answer.

Comment: To be honest: nobody would think parse_str() will do what it does when looking at the function name ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Regex are not the solution, as somebody [said](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001016.html):

> Some people, when confronted with a
>   problem, think "I know, I'll use
>   regular expressions." Now they have
>   two problems.

But nevermind that, what I would use, is [parse_url](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), and then append my `var1=1&var2=2` to the result query string. Something along the lines of:

```
$broken = parse_url($url);
$broken['query'] .= '&var1=1&var2=2';
if (strpos($broken,'&')==0) $broken['query'] = substr($broken['query'],1);
return $broken['scheme'].'://'.$broken['host'].$broken['path'].
  '?'.$broken['query'].'#'.$broken['fragment'];
```

If you don't want your variable to appear twice, use also [parse_str](http://php.net/parse_str) to break apart the query string.

Comment: parse_url() is definitely the right way to go about this. +1 for that. However, if parse_url were not available, regexp is a natural second choice, and I think it's reasonable to expect someone who's unaware of parse_url() to try to find a regexp solution. This is just one of those problems that regexp is suited towards. In fact, I would be surprised if PHP's own implementation of parse_url() did not employ regexps under the hood.

Comment: Maybe given php, the fastest solution is regex, but it *must* be encapsulated by a function. With C++, it's defenitely much less efficient and not good for general parsing of URLs.

We'll use parse_url whether it's given or not, if it's not given - we'll implement it. We might choose to implement it with a regex, but this is implementation detail and not the main cause.

Comment: @Alam Storm: LOL. I guess it's time for me to eat my own words.

@Elazar: I agree. I just think that it's unfair to characterize this problem as an example of poor use of regexp, even from a code-readability standpoint that Atwood is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Also the parse_str wont return any values as shown in the answer rather it takes an array as a param:

```
$array = array();    
parse_str($url,$array);
// $array will contain the ["scheme"] ["host"] etc
```

just a side note ;)

-- G